# using ASIHTTPRequest on iPhone to login to webservice written in Ruby on Rails and uses AuthLogic

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, asihttprequest

I have a website written in Ruby on Rails. Users can register & sign up on the website. I use AuthLogic for that I want to be able to do that using my iPhone app. It looks like ASIHTTPRequest is the best option for me to use.

So, I have a few questions ... how do I make sure I am sending the password & username somewhat securely? i.e. I don't want to send http://mysite.com/signup?u=X&p=y .

Secondly, should I store the persistent token, or should I store the username & password, or what?

I'm new to both web app making & iphone app making so I'm a bit stuck as to how to get started setting up such an API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the DiscussionBoard Example at [RESTKit](http://restkit.org)
it shows an elegant login and session managing